# Select where column contains three uppercase letters in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm using SQL Server 2019 and trying to debug my `ProperCase` function that converts strings to proper case.

I have a table which I used my function to create, containing all `varchar` columns, one of them is named `Surname`.

I want to select the rows where `Surname` contains three or more uppercase letters in a row.

I've searched this site and Google etc and there's plenty of examples for finding where there are *any* uppercase letters or *no* uppercase letters in a field, but this is a little more subtle than that.

The column can contain any *total* number of upper or lowercase letters, but I only want to select the rows where it contains three or more uppercase letters next to one another.

Could a regular expression work here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really any regex support in SQL Server natively unless you want to install custom CLR objects. If your data is stored as case insensitive and you want to perform case sensitive searches, one way is to use the `COLLATE` clause against the column.

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(i int, surname nvarchar(500));

INSERT @x(i, surname) VALUES
    (1, 'this is not a match'),
    (2, 'this is a MATCH'),
    (3, 'this is not a match'),
    (4, 'this is DEFINITELY a match');
    
DECLARE @min int = 3;

SELECT i, surname
  FROM @x
  WHERE surname COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 
  LIKE N'%' + REPLICATE(N'[A-Z]', @min) + N'%';
```

Results:

```
i      surname
----   -----------------------------
2      this is a MATCH
4      this is DEFINITELY a match
```

[This dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a5f96c81254e58baa4978af5b4c1cb7d) also demonstrates other values for `@min` (in case you want to identify 4, or 40, or 300 consecutive upper-case characters in a row).

Note this won't perform well, so hopefully it's not something you're doing often and at scale. Also it won't find a surname with other characters between the upper-case characters, like `Van DE Moor` or `MC-Adams`. Not that those are normal, but data isn't normal, and want you to understand the bill of goods.

Comment: Clever! Totally going to use this logic.

Comment: Perfect, amazing answer. I'm confused though, you say there's no Regex support in SQL natively, but then you use this in your code: '[A-Z]' which is a regex expression?

Comment: @Geoff I mean that it's so limited, you can barely call it support (I said "Not really any support" not "No support." Try do something even remotely more complex than this and you will be tearing your hair out.

Comment: Got you. This is also a very good tip, as the fact you can use *some* Regex makes you think that you could possibly use *any* Regex to solve this issue. I had started the tearing process.